# jQuery .html() removes all table related tags and breaking HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popover

I am fetching strange problem. I am using jQuery to execute AJAX request and trying to update a `div` content (bootstrap popover).

The AJAX is executed successfully and it is returning the HTML as output in debug.

```html
<a href = "javascript:void(0);" data-toggle = "popover" title = "<strong>Line Details</strong>"  data-placement = "top" data-html = "true" data-content = "<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:8pt;color:#bbb;">
    <tr style="background-color:#777;">
        <td style="width:40px">QTY</td>         
        <td style="width:180px">DESC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;">3</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;width:40px;"><input type="text" size="8" id="itemDesc-job1-1" name="job1itemDesc" value="Test Desc" >  </td>

</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">                        
      <div>&nbsp;<div>  <div id ="action-saveLineDetails-job1" class="icon-save" style="float:right !important;" title="Save" onclick="saveJobLineDetails('job1','3' )"></div>
    </td></tr> </table>" > 157|999</a>
```

Now, I am replacing the the `div` content (popover) like this:

```
$('#itemdetails-' + jobID).html(result.Data);
```

Surprisingly, it is removing all table related tags. 
The page is the showing something else. Here is the code what is found in that `div`:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="popover" title="<strong>Line Details</strong>" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-content="<table border=" 0"="" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:8pt;color:#bbb;">
                                    &nbsp;QTYDESCKG 
                                    31
                            <input type="text" size="8" id="itemDesc-job1-1" name="job1itemDesc" value="1">      
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;                      
                                      </a>
```

First time I am getting this type of wierd behavior of `.html()`.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You're using doublequotes to wrap your HTML content while they should be single - data-content = '<table border="0"  instead of data-content = "<table border="0".

Comment: Don't have spaces between your `=` and your attributes/values: `href = "javascript:void(0);"` should be `href="javascript:void(0);` Please fix these errors first and make sure you have a valid HTML